# Nginx server block resolves ip not Domain Name

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

This is my first Nginx server on Ubuntu 22.04. This is a learning project.

I have an Angular site running and using Nginx as a reverse proxy. I am trying to configure the Nginx server block according to this article here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

However I'm not understanding something in the article.

If I write my server block using an IP address like this it works browsing with the IP (I get my site not the Nginx welcome page).

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 185.###.###.###;
   location / {...}
```

If however I write my server block using a domain name and then browsing with the domain name it doesn't work. (I get the Nginx welcome page not the site).

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name mydomain.com;
   location / {...}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong or not understanding about the server block resolution process.

Comment: The `server_name` value must be an **exact match** of the text between the `//` and the first `/` in the requested URL. That means, if the request is prefixed with `www.`, then the `server_name` value must also be prefixed with `www.`, and vice versa.

Comment: You need an entry in your hosts File, /etc/hosts on Linux, or resolve the domain name in your DNS or Firewall:

185.###.###.### mydomain.com